# Не могу получить cookie файлы при использованни Axios

Tags: javascript, cookie, axios

При использовании fetch() я успешно получил куки файлы в моем браузере. Использовал следующий запрос:

```
  fetch("https://url", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
```

Но при попытке использовать запрос Axios я получаю ответ с сервера но при этом куки файлы не устанавливаются

```
axios.post("https://url", data, {
    params: {
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    },
  });
```

};
В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я получаю куки файлы в запросе но они не сохраняются в браузере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить параметр `withCredentials`

```
axios.post('your_url', data, {withCredentials: true});
```

Comment: Обновил запрос, я получаю куки файлы в результате запроса, но они не устанавливаются в браузере. При использовании fetch() все работает